# acl not overriding unix rights?

Tags: acl

I have a folder with UNIX rights that forbid access to me :

```
ls -l Sources-labo
drwxrwxrw-+ 6 nobody    applications 73728 févr. 25 13:25 Sources-labo

groups
users vault
```

*but* the ACL are set so that I should have access anyway (because of the group:users:rwx rule) :

```
getfacl Sources-labo/
# file: Sources-labo/
# owner: nobody
# group: applications
user::rwx
group::rwx
group:users:rwx
mask::rwx
other::rw-
```

However I cannot access this directory :

```
cd Sources-labo/
bash: cd: Sources-labo/: Permission denied
```

I read that the ACLs are supposed to override UNIX rights. How come I can't access this directory ?

Comment: Are you a member of the group "users" ? Verify:

`getent group \`id -G\``

This will print out what groups the current user is included in.

Comment: `users` appears in the list. Plus, I showed the output of `groups` in the first code sample

Comment: Strange...should work so...What is your OS ?

Comment: Perhaps the filesystem is mounted so it doesn't respect ACLs (option `noacl`, just running `mount` should tell)? Perhaps something else, like SELinux, is denying access?